# Name in left header, chapter in right header

Tags: header-footer

I am trying to work on my bachelor degree thesis and I need my name in the left header and chapter name in the right header, how can I do that?
I made something but it's displaying my name and the section name, but I need chapter.

```
\lhead{MITU ALEXANDRU PETRI\c{S}OR}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\rightmark}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}  
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\makeindex

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\usepackage[latin10]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{relsize}                 
\usepackage{textcomp}                 
\usepackage{eurosym}                   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{anysize}
%\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\settocbibname{References}


\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{courier}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small \ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\color{red}\hookrightarrow\space}},
  tabsize=3
}

\normalfont % in case the EC fonts aren't available

%\usepackage{amslatex}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\selectlanguage{romanian}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\sloppy
\nonfrenchspacing

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\graphicspath{{fig/}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\def\refname{Bibliografie} % la fel se redefinesc toate denumirile; pentru romana in romanian.ldf
\let\mylistof\listof \renewcommand\listof[2]{\mylistof{algorithm}{Listã de algoritmi}}
%\def\producelistofappendices{\listofappendices}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setcounter{page}{1}
%\pagestyle{headings}
\setcounter{footnote}{-1}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\lhead{ALEXANDRU PETRI\c{S}OR MITU}
\rhead[LE,RO]{\rightmark}


\begin{document}
```

Comment: `righthead` usually contains chapter-information and it is likely that something in your document redfines it. Can you show us a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) to understand what is going on?

Comment: `rightmark` usually contains section information, i was confused before. What is holding the chapter-info is `leftmark` ;-)

Comment: Your document ends in the middle of nowhere ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I did not post the entire code, I posted like 100 lines out of 1000.

Comment: @AlexandruMitu: Yes, completing it to a working example cost me some seconds, therefore my answer came too late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found the answer in

```
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{ALEXANDRU PETRI\c{S}OR MITU}
\fancyhead[RO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
```